# Shopify PostgreSQL Session Storage Doesn't Work

Tags: node.js, postgresql, shopify

I'm working to set up PostgresSQL Session Storage for my Shopify app using the direct [Shopify documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-node/blob/0be89329c70423a1c2356614c4a660b7f7bf36ae/src/auth/session/storage/README.md)

They say to set up Session Storage like so:

```
import Shopify from '@shopify/shopify-api';

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Auth.Session.PostgreSQLSessionStorage("postgres://username:password@host/database"),
  ...
});

// OR

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  SESSION_STORAGE: Shopify.Auth.Session.PostgreSQLSessionStorage.withCredentials(
    "host.com",
    "thedatabase",
    "username",
    "password",
  ),
  ...
});
```

However, when I set it up, I run into the following error:

```
Property 'Session' does not exist on type '{ SESSION_COOKIE_NAME: string; beginAuth(request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse, shop: string, redirectPath: string, isOnline?: boolean | undefined): Promise<...>; ... 4 more ...; getCurrentSessionId(request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse, isOnline?: boolean | undefined): string | undefined; }'.ts(2339)
}
```

My server crashes because: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PostgreSQLSessionStorage')`

I've tried importing `PostgreSQLSessionStorage` directly for use like so:

```
import { PostgreSQLSessionStorage } from "@shopify/shopify-api/dist/auth/session/index.js";
```

But that runs into a whole host of other undefined object issues.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I created my app from the CLI 3.0 tool, I have to migrate the project on Postgres before to deploy too. Really feel like they should provide clearer documentation for this

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this worked out? Removing Auth got me a little closer:

```
SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.PostgreSQLSessionStorage(`${process.env.DATABASE_URL}?sslmode=require`),
```

But now i get

```
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291801+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/process/promises:288
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291820+00:00 app[web.1]: triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291821+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291821+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291822+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: self-signed certificate
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291823+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1534:34)
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291823+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291823+00:00 app[web.1]: at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:948:8)
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291823+00:00 app[web.1]: at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:729:12) {
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291824+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
2022-08-01T00:21:05.291824+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Comment: Removing auth fixed it and then to fix the next error you're currently seeing, I set: `PGSSLMODE: no-verify`. I'm deployed to heroku so I just added it as a Config Vars. I'm still researching potential security implications but it works

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

Inquisitive Tom solution worked for me as well. To wrap it up, in order to switch to heroku postgresql from sqlite (original shopify CLI db), you have to:

- Deploy on heroku
- Create a db
- **Add "PGSSLMODE: no-verify" in Heroku Config Var**
- Get your database credentials in Heroku
- Replace below line of code in `Shopify.Context.initialize` inside index.js (be careful to replace all variables: username, password, host, database). **Don't include "auth"** as opposed to what is shown in Shopify Doc.

```
SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.PostgreSQLSessionStorage("postgres://username:password@host/database")
```